# p:inputText não está atualizando

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Tenho no seguinte código, um formulário que funciona tanto para alteração como pra adicionar uma entidade.

A lógica é a seguinte, tenho uma variável `alteracao`.

- se `alteracao == true` o formulário se comportará para alterar
- se `alteracao == false` o formulário se comportará para
  adicionar(default)

O estado dessa variável está sendo alterado no Managedbean da forma correta, tudo está rodando bem.

O problema está sendo "somente" na atualização dos campos do formulário na hora da alteração. Ao clicar no botão de ´Alterar´ na listagem(`datatable`), o objeto responsável por recuperar os inputs `entidade` está sendo setado da maneira correta, mas o formulário não atualiza com os seus valores. SOMENTE 'atualiza' para o valor de `Id`, que por padrão está escondido, mas ao clicar no botão alterar ele passa a ser renderizado e com o valor lá.

Eu queria, ao clicar no botão Alterar, que o formulário fosse preenchido com os valores do objeto que eu recuperei.

**Bean.java**

```
package managedbeans;

//imports.....

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Entidade> entidades;
    private List<String> campo2Disponiveis;

    private Entidade entidade;    

    private boolean alteracao;

    public List<Entidade> getEntidades() {
        return entidades;
    }

    public Entidade getEntidade() {
        return entidade;
    }

    public void setEntidade(Entidade entidade) {
        this.entidade = entidade;
    }

    public List<String> getCampo2Disponiveis() {
        return campo2Disponiveis;
    }

    public boolean isAlteracao() {
        return alteracao;
    }

    public void setAlteracao(boolean alteracao) {
        this.alteracao = alteracao;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        entidade = new Entidade();
        alteracao = false;

        carregaComponentes();
    }

    private void carregaComponentes() {
        EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntidadeDAO entidadeDAO = new EntidadeDAO(entityManager);

        entidades = entidadeDAO.getEntidades();
        campo2Disponiveis = entidades.stream().map(Entidade::getCampo2).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());


        entityManager.close();
    }

    public void adicionaOuAlteraEntidade() {
        EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntidadeDAO entidadeDAO = new EntidadeDAO(entityManager);

        if(alteracao) {
            alteracao = false;
            entidade = new Entidade();
        }else {
            entidadeDAO.inserir(entidade);
            entidades.add(entidade);
            entidades.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getCampo2().compareTo(o2.getCampo2()));
            entidade = new Entidade();
        }

        entityManager.close();
    }

    public void alteraEntidade() {
        alteracao = true;

        entidade = new Entidade(entidade);
    }

}
```

**.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
        <h2>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bean.alteracao ? 'Alterar' : 'Adicionar'}" />
        </h2>
        <p:panelGrid id="formGrid" columns="2">

            <p:outputLabel value="Id *" rendered="#{bean.alteracao}"/>
            <p:inputText id="id" placeholder="ID"
                value="#{bean.entidade.id}" readonly="true" 
                required="true" rendered="#{bean.alteracao}"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Campo 1" />
            <p:inputText value="#{bean.entidade.campo1}" placeholder="Descrição do campo 1" required="true"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Campo 2 *" />
            <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{bean.entidade.campo2}" placeholder="Selecione um campo2  ou crie um novo" effect="fold" editable="true" required="true" style="width: 100%">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.campo2Disponiveis}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

        </p:panelGrid>
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad" style="text-align: center">
            <p:commandButton
                value="#{bean.alteracao ? 'Alterar' : 'Adicionar'}"
                actionListener="#{bean.adicionaOuAlteraEntidade}"
                update="form" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <p:dataTable id="entidadesDataTableId"
            value="#{bean.entidades}" var="entidade"
            emptyMessage="Nenhuma entidade registrada" reflow="true">

            <f:facet name="header">Entidades</f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Id" style="text-align: center" width="20">
                <h:outputText value="#{entidade.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Campo 1" style="text-align: left">
                <h:outputText value="#{entidade.campo1}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Campo 2">
                <h:outputText value="#{entidade.campo2}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Alterar" style="text-align: center"
                width="70">
                <p:commandButton value="Alterar" immediate="true"
                    action="#{bean.alteraEntidade}" update="form">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{entidade}"
                        target="#{bean.entidade}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Comment: `update=":form:formGrid" não funciona?`

Comment: não, já tentei!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo fato do componente `<p:inputText>` ter uma regra ali de `rendered`, o processamento desse componente é pulado, ou seja, na fase 'apply request values' o JSF "pula" o processamento desse componente(Não tenho certeza, mas é defensivamente, pra evitar requisições maliciosas).

A forma de resolver esse problema é adicionando o atributo `proccess="@this"` no `<p:commandButton>` que dispara esse ajax garantindo a chamda do action passado no componente.

O código fica então

**Código do `<p:commandButton>`**

```
<p:column headerText="Alterar" style="text-align: center" width="70">
    <p:commandButton value="Alterar" immediate="true" process="@this"
        action="#{bean.alteraEntidade}" update="form">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{entidade}"
            target="#{bean.entidade}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```